# Why are the hearts in turtle appearing slanted?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

def heart(x):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, -100)
    t.pendown()

    t.color('black','red')
    t.begin_fill()
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(100)
    t.circle(50, 180)
    t.right(90)
    t.circle(50, 180)
    t.forward(100)
    t.end_fill()


for i in range(3):
    if i==1:
        x=-250
        heart(x)
    elif i==2:
        #continue
        x=0
        heart(x)
    else:
        #continue
        x=250
        heart(x)


t.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

This program is supposed to draw three hearts in a straight line
I've made a loop that sets the initial position of the heart. It's supposed to draw the heart in one position and move to the next position. While the pointer is moving over the next position, the hearts are appearing slanted.

Comment: An image of the result would help

Comment: In what direction is the turtle pointing after it completes one heart? What is the starting direction for the next one?

Comment: The hearts should be facing upwards

Comment: That link is private - I cannot see contents (FYI you can paste screenshots into your question). Those hearts *should* be facing upwards, but how are they oriented now? My *guess* is that after drawing one heart, you should rotate the mouse to point upwards (or whatever the start direction is) again

Comment: In your code you have a `t.left(45)` and a `t.right(90)`, which totals to a `t.right(45)` between the hearts, that's how they gradually get rotated, the second one by 45 degrees, the third one by 90 (both compared to the first one). Moving around doesn't reset the orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `heart` function assumes the turtle's heading is 0, but in the course of drawing a heart, heading changes due to `left`/`right` calls.

One solution is to reset heading with `t.setheading(0)` at the start of the function.

Also, your loop/`if` combo is overcomplicated. I suggest either removing the `if`s or removing both the loop and the `if`s and using 3 separate `heart` calls. Here's a simplified version:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def heart(x):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, -100)
    t.pendown()
    t.color("black", "red")
    t.setheading(0)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(100)
    t.circle(50, 180)
    t.right(90)
    t.circle(50, 180)
    t.forward(100)
    t.end_fill()


t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()

for x in range(-250, 251, 250):
    heart(x)

Screen().exitonclick()
```

Consider making `size` and `y` values parameters for `heart`, and optionally `t`. As is, it's a bit on the hardcoded side.